# values store in struct

Tags: c, kernel, embedded-linux, void, void-pointers

i'm new to C language. I have some questions to ask regarding structs.

For example:

```
static inline void *mmc_priv(struct mmc_host *host)
{        
     return (void *)host->private;
}

struct mmc_host 
{
    unsigned long private[0] ____cacheline_aligned;
};


struct mmc_davinci_host *host = NULL;
struct mmc_host *mmc = NULL;

host = mmc_priv(mmc);
host->mmc = mmc;
```

*for the `struct mmc_davinci_host` please refer to this site http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/mmc/host/davinci_mmc.c#L167*

The function `mmc_priv()` returns a void pointer. So, where does `host` store the returned address since `host` is a struct type?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning `void*` does not mean to return a `void` pointer. It means to return **a pointer to any type**.
In fact, pointers store addresses, and addresses always have the same size, no matter which type is located behind.

However, you should have a cast to `struct mmc_davinci_host *` after calling `mmc_priv`. I would write it as follows:

```
/* call mmc_priv and store its result in host, after having cast it to struct mmc_davinci_host * */
host = (struct mmc_davinci_host *) mmc_priv(mmc);
```

Comment: Yes.I do understand the `void*` is to casting to any type.But since struct has its own declared members.Where are the address store?Is it at the 1st byte of `struct`??

Comment: `host` is a pointer, not directly a `struct`. It points to a `struct` where the members are located.

Comment: okkk.I understand it already. i miss that host is a pointer.Thamk for pointing it out.Do you have any good e-book/site for learning advance C?

Comment: @spaceboy: For ebook list refer [this link on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books) and [this link on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) for C programming books

Comment: The conversion from `void*` can be done implicitly; the cast is unnecessary.

Comment: @spaceboy: look at the eBooks link that another.anon.coward pointed out

Comment: @Keith Thompson: of course it's implicit. However, verbosity is always better in software engineering. The clearer the code, the better.

Comment: @jHackTheRipper: Not always.  For example, a cast can mask a failure to include a declaration for `mmc_priv`, which (prior to C99) causes the compiler to assume that it returns `int`.  C has implicit conversions for a reason.

Comment: @Keith Thomspon: that is why is not the safest language ever! But I would encourage every programmer to add these explicit casts, coupled with a comment so that in case of failure, it could be a hint to debug.

Comment: @jHackTheRipper: The casts add *nothing* to the program's functionality or safety.